How can I enable PMU driver in a LXD VM to get hardware events with perf
I run lxd 6.1 on an Intel i9-1390.
On the host I can run perf and get all the hardware events.
In the VM I can run perf but do not the hardware events.
The command line has the -cpu host,hv_passthrough set.
 701512 ?        Sl    13:41 /snap/lxd/30130/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -S -name c0-rl -uuid 49ba3cce-de29-43ca-8400-4f1ded88a55d -daemonize -cpu host,hv_passthrough -nographic -serial chardev:console -nodefaults -no-user-config -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=allow,spawn=allow,resourcecontrol=deny -readconfig /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/xxx/qemu.conf -spice unix=on,disable-ticketing=on,addr=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/xxx/qemu.spice -pidfile /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/xxx/qemu.pid -D /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/xxx/qemu.log -smbios type=2,manufacturer=Canonical Ltd.,product=LXD -runas lxd -bios /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/seabios/bios-256k.bin

dmesg on the VM shows:
[    0.223566] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 183 no PMU driver, software events only.

perf on the VM shows:
root@rlsdwan-vnf:~# perf stat sleep 1

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

          0.84 msec task-clock                #    0.001 CPUs utilized          
             1      context-switches          #    1.188 K/sec                  
             1      cpu-migrations            #    1.188 K/sec                  
            80      page-faults               #   95.079 K/sec                  
  <not supported>      cycles                                                      
  <not supported>      instructions                                                
  <not supported>      branches                                                    
  <not supported>      branch-misses                                               

   1.001526172 seconds time elapsed

   0.001466000 seconds user
   0.000000000 seconds sys

On the host I get the not supported values.
Can anybody help?
Andreas
